# onSelect function in antd calendar component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

How to get the selected date inside the onSelect function, after update the selected date in the state and

```
onSelect = (cal) => {
      this.setState({  selectedValue: cal   });
      alert(this.state.selectedValue);
```

I got the previous date in the alert but i need the current selected date, how to achieve this...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem here is that `this.setState({})` is asynchronous. That means that alert can happen before state gets updated. What you can do is pass a callback.
Check this example which logs state after it has been updated:

```
this.setState({ selectedValue: cal }, () =>
      console.log(this.state.selectedValue);
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

From the antd [docs](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/#DatePicker), `DatePicker` uses an `onChange` event, not `onSelect`.

This should log the correct value.

```
<DatePicker
    format="MM/DD/YYYY"
    placeholder="Banana"
    locale="en_US"
    onChange={console.log}
/>
```